# Paramiko Issues - Channel Closed when Executing a Command

Tags: python, paramiko

I've been trying to run commands on an [Overture Box](http://es.overturenetworks.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_image_large/images/products/Overture_6000_front.png) using paramiko to establish the SSH connection.

My script does connect properly to the box, no issues are seen, the problem comes when the script runs the exec_command(cmd) method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("version")
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 345, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 60, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 229, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1086, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Same script using a Linux Box as the target host yields the proper results

The code is borrowed, I just found the snippet Googling:

```
import sys
import time
import select
import paramiko

host = raw_input("Hostname?: ")
i = 1
password = raw_input("Password?: ")


#
# Try to connect to the host.
# Retry a few times if it fails.
#
while True:
    print "Trying to connect to %s (%i/30)" % (host, i)

    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host, port=22, username="username", password=password)
        print "Connected to %s" % host
        break
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print "Authentication failed when connecting to %s" % host
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        print "Could not SSH to %s, waiting for it to start" % host
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)

    # If we could not connect within time limit
    if i == 30:
        print "Could not connect to %s. Giving up" % host
        sys.exit(1)

# Send the command (non-blocking)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("version")

# Wait for the command to terminate
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
    if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
        if len(rl) > 0:
           # Print data from stdout
            print stdout.channel.recv(1024),

#
# Disconnect from the host
#
print "Command done, closing SSH connection"
ssh.close()
```

I found other questions where it's said that the issue might be related to the SFTP settings in the host, but I'm able to do:

```
sftp username@hostname
```

I've Googled for a while but I can't find anything helpful so far.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Almost forgot, I know the issue is exactly at:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("version")
```

I've run the whole script interactively and it breaks when I run that line.

Comment: It fails in wait_for_event - does it fail instantly, or wait a while for a timeout? What does `version` do if you SSH in and run it normally - is it just one line of numbers, or is it more than that? Does it prompt for a keypress or anything? Is the Overture running Linux or running some custom OS - could you redirect the output of version to a file and see if the command runs then?

Comment: It's instantly. If I log into the device through a terminal and run it, it works. It's just a line. It doesn't prompt. It's running a UNIX based OS I believe, not 100% sure.

The last question I don't understand it, sorry. Could you explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be that the Overture does not support the SSH exec_command request.

I have needed to use `transport.open_session()`, and `session.get_pty()` and `session.invoke_shell()` to setup an interactive shell session, then use `session.send()` and `session.recv()` to write/read to the shell session for Cisco switches and other network appliances, when `exec_command()` is not available.

Comment: I'll try this and I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: Ok, I'll take your answer as good. I still can't make it work but that's due to my lack of knowledge of how the Channel class works. At least now I can send the command to the device, the issue is that is not reading everything back.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Probably a bit misleading in my original answer. You should get the return value of `session.invoke_shell()` in a channel variable - it returns a paramiko.Channel object. it is this socket-like object that you can do send and recv calls to control the underlying interactive shell session.

After doing `channel.send('version\n')` (or whatever command text), you should either delay for a short interval, or check `channel.recv_ready()` prior to doing a `channel.recv(len)`.

Comment: Unlike the `exec_command()` call, you won't get a definitive status code, or indication that the process is complete, you'll just have to read shell output until you hopefully get back to a prompt string. Things are so much easier when `exec_command()` is supported :)

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: I'm glad i found this answer, as invoking a shell was what i needed to solve my problem :) +1

Answer (score 0):

here is a workaround for this,

1. get a transport for your connection.
2. open a session.
3. then `exec_command(command) and then`recv()`, no need for sleep.

   ```
   client.connect("host", port=22, username="user",password= "pass",look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

   transport=client.get_transport()
   channel = t.open_session()

   channel.exec_command(command)
   out = channel.recv(-1)
   print(out.decode())
   ```